# Angular CKEditor Cannot set data property with required values

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

I am building an angular application which utilizes CKEditor.
I am trying to load data into the editor based on content pulled from the database so a user can edit it. This issue is when i try to set the data as the string pulled from the database, the editor is always blank. However, when i copy and paste the string (the EXACT SAME STRING) it works perfectly fine. I cannot seem to find the source of this issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

You Can see in the image at the bottom how it SHOULD work, and it does work when setting the string directly even with the identical text, but when i try to use the data i get from my db, nothing. I have view that the string is correct when inspecting the console.

Thank you.

RELEVANT CODE
//sets the value based on an input object property

```
ngOnChanges() :void{
    console.log(this.currentProduct);
    this.productForm.setValue({
      categoryName : this.currentProduct.category.categoryName,
      name : this.currentProduct.name,
      price : this.currentProduct.price,
      inStock : this.currentProduct.inStock,
      stockQty : this.currentProduct.stockQty
    });
    this.productDescription = this.currentProduct.desc.valueOf();    
    console.log(this.productForm.value, this.productDescription);
  }
```

html

```
<div class="form-control d-flex" style="flex-direction: column">
            <label for="productDescription" class="">Product Description</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <ckeditor
                [editor]="Editor"
                [data]="productDescription"
                (change)="ckEditOnChange($event)"
                style="width: 100%"
              ></ckeditor>
            </div>
          </div>
```

example of when it kinda works

```
  ngOnChanges() :void{
    console.log(this.currentProduct);
    this.productForm.setValue({
      categoryName : this.currentProduct.category.categoryName,
      name : this.currentProduct.name,
      price : this.currentProduct.price,
      inStock : this.currentProduct.inStock,
      stockQty : this.currentProduct.stockQty
    });
    this.productDescription = "<p>this is my description</p>";    
    console.log(this.productForm.value, this.productDescription);
  }
```

[image: How it should look]

Comment: Just to add to this, I also tested with various database string and the issue persists no matter what the stored string value is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved that obstacle by adding `[formControlName]` directive on `ckeditor` angular component. Then you van set/get values like from ordinary form element of `ReactiveFormsModule`.

**Note:** In that case `data` and `change` attributes are not needed any more

```
 <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" formControlName="FORM_CONTROL_NAME"></ckeditor>
```

Comment: yes thanks I ended up coming to the same conclusion. Their documentation was somewhat misleading in regards to the data binding.

Answer (score 0):

Angular HTML file

> <app-ckeditor #myEditor>

Then on component

> @ViewChild("myEditor", { static: false }) myEditor: any;

And you can simple pass

> this.myEditor.data = DATA_YOU_WANT_TO_PASS